# Reset Django Database 1.8 Can I still create a new superuser?

Tags: django, sqlite

I have seem to messed up my database badly and am getting all sorts of funky database errors.  How can I wipe the database, but still be able to add a new superuser so I can set it back up?  I see the flush command, but I'm concerned I won't be able to re add the superuser, and I cannot find anywhere to confirm this.  Can anyone help me out and tell me the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Oh I'm using sqlite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I messed things up or just want a clean state, I just erase the database with

```
$ echo "" > database.sqlite   # database.sqlite is your database file
```

Then, just run *normal* commands:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```